# A Co rious message

Tags: cipher, science

> sega srmo bryp druc omom ogaz nbrz rcoa gzrb rcdg arur hgag ecoc updn brus b---

`-` indicates the end of the message.

What is this message trying to tell me? Also what is its origin?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Break the message into

> element symbols:
> `Se Ga Sr Mo Br Y Pd Ru Co Mo Mo Ga Zn Br Zr Co Ag Zr Br Cd Ga Ru Rh Ga Ge Co Cu Pd Nb Ru Sb`

Then get the

> atomic numbers:
> `34 31 38 42 35 39 46 44 27 42 42 31 30 35 40 27 47 40 35 48 31 44 45 31 32 27 29 46 41 44 51`

Finally,

> subtract 26 from everything and convert using A=1, B=2 etc.:
> `HELP I'M TRAPPED IN A UNIVERSE FACTORY`

The message is from

> https://xkcd.com/10/